# Criar Tabela de Impostos SQL

Tags: sql, pascal, lazarus

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para orçamentos e, para finalizar meu projeto, preciso criar uma tabela de impostos. Para ajudar, segue um exemplo do que quero fazer: na tabela de matéria prima, cada material tem um imposto de compra e essa quantidade de impostos sobre o produto pode ser alterada de tempos em tempos. Então eu criei uma lista de impostos, onde eu quero, por exemplo, num cadastro deixar os impostos: PIS,COFINS,ICMS. E no cadastro de matéria prima anexar a lista de impostos ao invés de selecionar imposto por imposto.

**PRINTS DAS TABELAS:**

[image: Tabela LISTA DE IMPOSTOS]
[image: Tabela IMPOSTOS]
[image: Tabela MATÉRIA PRIMA]

Espero ter explicado bem o meu problema, mas caso alguém queira mais alguma explicação, é só chamar.

Comment: Acho que deu pra entender, mas qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Resolvi minha pergunta externamente, mesmo assim obrigado! @KhaosDoctor